# Convert string to object name Java

Tags: java, string, object, type-conversion

it might be a simple question or even impossible without any kind of Interface (Arrays, Maps etc.) but I would like to know if there's any possibility of converting an object name to String so I can pass as argument. I have two classes Paciente and Sintomas with multiple objects that I need to pass as argument to a function but I don't want to use arrays (it must be like that) and I can't figure any other way of doing so without manually make an insert for each one.

```
Paciente Paciente1 = new Paciente("001", "Ana Melo", 33, "");
Paciente Paciente2 = new Paciente("002", "Rui Costa", 13, "");
Paciente Paciente3 = new Paciente("003", "Joana Martins", 85, "");
Paciente Paciente4 = new Paciente("004", "Pedro Torres", 53, "");
Paciente Paciente5 = new Paciente("005", "Ana Gomes", 93, "");
Paciente Paciente6 = new Paciente("006", "Jorge Costa", 56, "");

Sintomas Sintoma1 = new Sintomas("001", "febre");
Sintomas Sintoma2 = new Sintomas("001", "dores");
Sintomas Sintoma3 = new Sintomas("001", "machas");
Sintomas Sintoma4 = new Sintomas("002", "febre");
Sintomas Sintoma5 = new Sintomas("002", "manchas");
Sintomas Sintoma6 = new Sintomas("003", "febre");
Sintomas Sintoma7 = new Sintomas("003", "dores");
Sintomas Sintoma8 = new Sintomas("004", "febre");
Sintomas Sintoma9 = new Sintomas("006", "manchas");
Sintomas Sintoma10 = new Sintomas("006", "dores");

// now I would like to pass to a function as argument something like this:

for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    kSession.insert("Paciente"+(i+1));

// instead of making 

kSession.insert(Paciente1);
kSession.insert(Paciente2);
kSession.insert(Paciente3);

// and so on.
```

Comment: `Paciente` and `Sintomas` mean "patient" and "symptoms" in Spanish, for those who are curious.

Comment: So you want eval basically... use an array...

Comment: Objects don't have names. Use a reference. Are you looking for a `Map`?

Comment: you have to define all the values anyway, however the question is a bit vague, you want a container ? and it can't be a list ? well .... you CAN use a Map, but then it is not rly better than a list in this context

Comment: Classes have names (`Sintomas.class.getName()` should return `"Sintomas"`). Objects don't.

Comment: Well .getClass().toString() returns the implementations name at runtime, but it has to be like Object object = new someImpl(); then it will return "class implName"

Comment: maybe `kSession.insert(new Paciente("001", "Ana Melo", 33, ""));` would be sufficient?

Comment: Just make an Arraylist... `kSession.insert(pacientes.get(i+1))`. No reason not to

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for your comment, I think I missed that line. Already deleted my answer ;) However it's like a really weird way of trying to solve this problem, not using an array

Comment: "I don't want to use arrays (it must be like that)" -- You're really going to have to explain why not. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work(asuming you mean no array because of size constraints), note that there has to be somewhere you add the data, it's also possible to load it from a txt or something, but it has to be defined at some point

```
List<Paciente> pacientes = new ArrayList<>(); // no size constraints, automatically expands if too small

pacientes.add(new Paciente("", "", ""));

for (Paciente paciente : pacientes) { // loop all Patientes in pacientes
    kSession.insert(paciente); // add a paciente to the session, for every entry
}
```

ofcource same can be done for any class, or object

It all really comes down to, how do you wish to store and access the data, and where do you need to store and access it. Using ArrayList and Map's offer the utility of easily changing the size and content of a list of data, but as any data it must be initially inserted

As a side note if the patients have an ID then using a Map

```
Map<String, Paciente> pacientes = new HashMap<>();
```

provides a way to acces the patiens very fast, and the TreeMap structure is sorted on key, should that be needed.

Other options could be 
Wrapper classes that manage the data, will work similarily to an ArrayList<> but you can define, rules for adding, deleting, and such from the list.

```
public class Wrapper{
    private List<Paciente> pacientes = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPaciente(Paciente paciente){
        if(!this.pacientes.contains(paciente)) // prevent multi entries
            paciente.add(paciente);
    }

    public void addPacientes(List<Paciente> pacientes){
        for(Paciente paciente : pacientes) // add all patients using the add method
            this.addPaciente(paciente);
    }

    public List<Paciente> getPacientes(){
        return this.pacientes;
    }
}
```

You can then add the patients to the kSession, as earlier described

Finally, there is no reason why Paciente, can have the list of Sintomas, such that

```
public class Paciente{
    private List<Sintomas> sintomas = new ArrayList<>();

    public addSintomas(Sintomas sintomas){
        if(!this.sintomas.contains(sintomas))
            this.sintomas.add(sintomas);
    }
    // rest is the same principle as above in "Wrapper"
}
```

This way you can get a Paciente, and add a Sintomas, and then when you wish to check a Pacientes Sintomas you can just get the list of Sintomas from that Paciente

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I don't want to use arrays or maps. I rather want java to get an object by passing the name as string. Probably isn't possible I don't know.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo what you are descriping here is excatly what a map is, it's a way to store values based on a key for instance a string, and then get it back using said string Map<String, Object>, for reference if you mean an object TYPE then save it as .getClass().toStrin() and then get it byt looping thought it looking for the same .getClass().toString() note that that is IMPLEMENTATION not the interface, that it will look for then. But you have to realise you can't look for something unless you saved it in a data structure or do it by it's name